# Custom Excel 2013 UI does not appear to be working

Tags: vba, xaml

I have an Add-in created in Excel 2013 that I am attempting to call through a custom ribbon created through Custom UI Editor for Microsoft Office.

I have created the XAML and it is as follows:

```
  <customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
    <ribbon startFromScratch="false">
        <tabs>
            <tab id="customTab" label="TestTab">
                <group id="customGroup" label="TestGroup">
                    <button id="scanStart" label="Scan Test" imageMso="HappyFace" size="large" onAction="Yolo_eventhandler" />
                </group>
            </tab>
        </tabs>
    </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

within the Add-in I have the following:

```
Sub Yolo_eventhandler(control As IRibbonControl)
MsgBox "YOLO"
End Sub
```

I have checked the add-in is installed, and I have confirmed the add-in is running when excel starts by adding a msgbox in the add-ins "onLoad" event. I can also run macros that I have manually added to the ribbon.
The error message I am getting is: "Cannot run the macro 'Yolo_eventhandler'. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled".
I have checked my trust settings and the folder this add-in is located (the default add-ins folder) is definately trusted.
Interestingly, when I copy the eventhandler code to a module in an xlsx file I also have open it works perfectly.
Can anyone suggest how to get this correctly firing from the add-in?

Comment: The code seems good to me, I replaced my code in an existing add-in and it works fine.  I normally create a module called 'Ribbon' to put the callback functions.  Where is `Yolo_eventhandler` in your add-in?  You can also check the ribbon is loading properly by addin an `OnLoad` callback after the opening <customUI in the XML

Answer (score 1):

I managed to resolve this issue - I was missing a reference to the "Microsoft Office 15.0 Object Library" in the add-in I was trying to call this from. It was hard to find this error as the ribbon would not give me this error, it was only when I went into my add-in and tried to run another function and it wouldn't compile. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Thanks - I just had this error too, but my problem was that the VB did not compile. Running it standalone showed that, as you suggested. Ta